# C++ Template class definition and declaration seperation

Tags: c++, templates

c++.why can't you separate the definition of your templates class from their declaration and put them inside a .cpp file? is there a workaround to allow the separation.
And could anybody give my a source where I could also get more information with examples.
Thanks

Comment: Simple answer is it can't be done. Only one compiler ever implemented this originally, and now it's been given up as a lost cause.

Comment: ... 4, 3, 2, 1, `*'|'*`!

Comment: @PeterR Simple answer is it can be done, but you have to be careful with what you do with the `.cpp` file.

Comment: @juanchopanza depends on your definition of "done". No explicit instatiations, and full template definition in a separate translation unit cannot be done, and I guess that's what I thought the OP meant. EDG was the only compiler to ever implement `export` AFAIK.

Comment: if you dont want to help then dont. leaving smart comments only makes you look like an ass.